# Generate PDF from other PDFs with page numbers

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdftk

As part of a project I'm undertaking, I need to try and merge a number of PDFs I have and place consecutive page numbers on each (which may not start from 1). Ideally, I need to be able to call this from a Java program.

I know there are tools such as *iText*, *PDFBox* and *Pdftk*, but are these able to deal with the page numbers? I have looked into them and haven't found any ability to deal with this.

**Are there any tools you know of that can achieve this?**

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0646.html example code. you could add additional text/images/whatever using PdfContentByte from PDFWriter getDirectContent() method.

Comment: Thanks very much, that seems to fit exactly with what I'm after! Perfect example

Comment: :D May the bit and byte will be with you :D

Comment: Need everything I can get, in the fight against ridiculous and far-reaching client wishes!